# Can't get 'plotweb' in the Biparite package to work (R)

Tags: r, csv, networking, bipartite

I am trying to visualise a biparite network using the `biparite` package in R. My data consists of 4 columns in a spreadsheet. The columns contain 
1) plant species names
2) bee species names
 3) site 
 4) interaction frequency. 
I first read the data into R from a CSV file, then convert it to a web using the helper function `frame2webs`. When I then try to visualise the network with `plotweb()` I get the error message:

> Error in web[rind, cind, drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions

My code looks like this:

```
library(bipartite)
bee <- read.csv('TestFile.csv')
bees <- as.data.frame(bee)
BeeWeb <- frame2webs(bees, type.out = "array")
plotweb(BeeWeb)
```

I've also tried:

```
BeeWeb <- frame2webs(bees, 
          varnames = c("higher","lower","webID","freq"), 
          type.out = "array")
```

Please help! I am new to R and am struggling to make this work. Cheers!

Comment: Could you post the output of `dput(bee)` ?

Comment: (1) `read.csv` generates a data frame, no need for the additional `as.data.frame`. (2) The `varnames` in `frame2webs` should correspond to the column names in your CSV file: see `?frame2webs`. (3) `plotweb` expects a matrix (or perhaps data frame) as input, you have an array. So `plotweb(as.data.frame(BeeWeb))` may work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your data look like, but this happens to me when I have a single factor level in either the "higher" or "lower" column, type.out is "list", and emptylist is TRUE.

This is due to a problem in empty, a function that frame2webs only calls when type.out is "list" and emptylist is TRUE. empty finds the dimensions of your data using NROW and NCOL, which interpret a single row of input as a vertical vector. When there's only one factor level in "lower" or "higher", the input to empty is a one-row array. empty interprets this row as a column, hence the 'incorrect number of dimensions' error.

Two simple workarounds:

1. Set type.out to "array"
2. Set emptylist to FALSE